# why this recursive implicit for Functor is not resolved

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I am learning about `Functor[F[_]]`s. I would like to provide implicit Functors for all cases where I want to map over 'leaf' elements in collections.

For example given instances:

```
val collection0 = List(1,2,3)
val collection1 = List(Some(1))
val collection2 = List(List(Some(2)))
val collection3 = Option(List(Some(3), None, Some(0)))
```

Now if I want to map over elements using Functors I need to provide theirs instances:

```
import cats.Functor  //scalaz can be used here instaed
import cats.std.option._  //this brings Functor[Option] into scope
import cats.std.list._    //and this brings Functor[List] into scope
```

This will work:

```
Functor[List].map(collection0)(_ + 1)
```

At this point below will not work because of missing implicits (as expected):

```
type LO[X] = List[Option[X]]
Functor[LO].map(collection1) (_ + 1)  //could not find implicit value for parameter instance: cats.Functor[LO]
type LLO[X] = List[List[Option[X]]]
Functor[LLO].map(collection2) (_ + 1) //ditto
type OLO[X] = Option[List[Option[X]]]
Functor[LLO].map(collection2) (_ + 1) //ditto
```

I can simple fix it by providing composed Functors:

```
implicit val loFunctor = Functor[List] compose Functor[Option]
implicit val lloFunctor = Functor[List] compose Functor[List] compose Functor[Option]
implicit val oloFunctor = Functor[Option] compose Functor[List] compose Functor[Option]
```

... well - this looks a little bit like boilerplate, doesn't it?

Trying be a clever developer I figured out that If I just use some recursive style of providing all this Functors then it migth help. This is what I developed:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
implicit def autoComposedFunctor[A[_] : Functor, B[_] : Functor]: Functor[Lambda[a => A[B[a]]]] = Functor[A] compose Functor[B]

//or the same without kind projector support:
implicit def autoComposedFunctor[A[_] : Functor, B[_] : Functor]: Functor[({type L[X] = A[B[X]]})#L] = Functor[A] compose Functor[B]
```

And it's almost working. At least for the `collection1` but it didn't provide implicit Functors for examples with `collection2` and `collection3`.

I thought that `autoComposedFunctor[List, Option]` will provide in implicit scope value of type `Functor[List[Option]]` so next time it can be picked up and use to provide `Functor[Option[List[Option]]]` by calling the same function with previously provided instance. But id didn't.

Any ideas why?

(scalaVersion was "2.11.6")

Comment: BTW: Can please someone create 'cats' tag - http://typelevel.org/cats/

Comment: There's a `scala-cats` tag, which I think is the best we're going to get, but that's one of the dangers of naming a project "cats". :)

Comment: @TravisBrown - thanks :) I missed it.